# Symfony DataFixtures wierd behavior when referencing another record

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Downloaded Symfony and DataFixtureBundle (http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html)

My db structure:

[image: DB Structure (partial)]

In general:

A `book` will have many headlines, and each `headline` has many reviews. It is a very simple one-may relationship.

In db, the index, FK are all setup.

Then I write 4 fixture files:

```
<?php

namespace tr\rsywxBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use \Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use \Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use \tr\rsywxBundle\Entity\BookPlace as BookPlace;

class LoadPlaceData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    /**
     * 
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        //Create a common place
        $place1=new BookPlace();
        $place1->setName('Common');
        $this->addReference('commonPlace', $place1);

        //Create a special place
        $place2=new BookPlace();
        $place2->setName('Special');
        $this->addReference('specialPlace', $place2);

        $manager->persist($place1);
        $manager->persist($place2);

        $manager->flush();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
       return 2; 
    }
}
```

All other 3 are similar. The 1 is load `publisher`, 2 for `place`, 3 for `book`, 4 for `headline`.

When trying to load the datafixtures, it always says:

[image]

However, if I put nothing in `headline` load() function, it works fine. This means, the `book` is getting the reference from `publiser` and `place`. The error also shows that the `getReference` in LoadBook fixture file is not working.

Does this bundle not support such a cascading one-many relationship?

Comment: There's a notice error in LoadHeadLine.php, can you show it plz ?

Comment: @VBee I did not see the notice error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have identified the problem.

The `setBookid($this->getReference(...))` can only be effective if and only if:

1. The `headline` table's `bookid` column is referencing the `book` table's PK.

In my case, PK in `book` table is an auto-increment, while in my current setup, the `headline` table's `bookid` is referring an unique index, other than the PK.

So, even though the above setup works fine for a normal setup, data fixtures are that smart to grab the `bookid` from the referenced object. Thus generates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Care of the name you give to your fields:

there's a list a reserved word in any database

(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html) and "show" seems to be reserved.

Comment: dropped that column "show" and re-import, regenerate the entities, and re-run load job but still the same error.